# How to do this type-safely: "the types 'Vehicle<C>' and 'Vehicle<CarConfig>' have no overlap"

Tags: typescript

This code (which is weird, but I did it only to pose this question):

```
interface Vehicle<C> {
    id: string
    name: string
    config: C | null
}

interface CarConfig {
    leatherSeats: boolean
}

const Car: Vehicle<CarConfig> = {
    id: "car",
    name: "car",
    config: null
}

interface TruckConfig {
    numberOfWheels: number
}

const Truck: Vehicle<TruckConfig> = {
    id: "truck",
    name: "truck",
    config: null
}

function getVehicleConfig<C>(vehicle: Vehicle<C>): C | null {
    if (vehicle === Car) {
        return vehicle.config
    }
    if (vehicle === Truck) {
        return vehicle.config
    }
    throw new Error("Unknown vehicle")
}
```

Compiles with this error:

```
src/explain.ts:28:9 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Vehicle<C>' and 'Vehicle<CarConfig>' have no overlap.
```

The expectation here is that (due to constraints in another part of the software) `vehicle` in `getVehicleConfig` will always be either the `Car` object or the `Truck` object, and `getVehicleConfig` will return the config associated with the instance.

What is the right way to express `getVehicleConfig` in a type safe manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go would be a discriminated union :

```
type VehiculeType= 'Car' | 'Truck';


interface Vehicle<C> {
    id: string
    name: string
    config: C | null
    type: VehiculeType;
}

interface CarConfig {
    leatherSeats: boolean
}

const Car: Vehicle<CarConfig> = {
    type: 'Car',
    id: "car",
    name: "car",
    config: null
}

interface TruckConfig {
    numberOfWheels: number
}

const Truck: Vehicle<TruckConfig> = {
    type: 'Truck',
    id: "truck",
    name: "truck",
    config: null
}

function getVehicleConfig<C>(vehicle: Vehicle<C>): C | null {
    if (vehicle.type === 'Car') {
        return vehicle.config
    }
    if (vehicle.type === 'Truck') {
        return vehicle.config
    }
    throw new Error("Unknown vehicle") 
}
```